# Error in validator. Can you help me?

Tags: php, validation

Can you help me with this error on my web-site?

> Error: document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

And I found this part of code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->categories as $cat){
           echo '<span>'.$cat->category_name_rus.' ';
                if(count($cat->products)>0){
                    echo '<div class="hover"><ul>';
                        foreach ($cat->products as $product) {
                            echo '<li><a href="/product/'.$product->id.'"><div class="left_act">'.$product->product_name_rus.'</div><div class="right_act"></div></a></li>';
                        }
                echo '</ul><div></div></div>';
                }
           echo '</span>';
        }?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: how to yuo ran this script, and show source code pls.

Comment: Copy the output of the code and paste here https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: span is an inline element, so having a div inside span is a bad idea, also, it would be better, if you nest span inside span and give inner span OR span inside div.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:

you **close the two times of div** without open div

So Please Change

```
echo '</ul><div></div></div>';
```

into

```
echo '</ul><div>';
```

More over `<span>` tag is inline element. `div` is not use as child element in `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, you shouldn't have a `span` tag containing block elements such as `divs`. The [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element) indicates that only phrasing elements should be contained in spans.

> Content model: **Phrasing content.**

Also [from](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2):

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing
>   content form paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
<?php foreach ($this->categories as $cat) : ?>
   <div>
        <span><?php echo $cat->category_name_rus.' '; ?></span>
        <?php
        if(count($cat->products)>0){
            ?>
            <div class="hover">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($cat->products as $product) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/product/".<?php echo $product->id;?> >
                                <div class="left_act">
                                    <?php echo $product->product_name_rus; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right_act">

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>';
        }
   </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Hope it will help you....